# How to remove cookies completely using useCookies in React without leaving undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

So I have a django-react application where I use django-rest-framework token authentication package. I would fetch the token from an API call and insert it into a hook (useCookies) that would be stored in as a cookie. The code i have for it is as follow:

```
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

const Home = () => {
     const[token, setToken, removeToken] = useCookies(['loginToken']);
}

const loginBtn = () => {
  APIService.LoginUser({
    username: username,
    password: password,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      setToken("loginToken", response.token);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

now I'm trying to create a logout functionality where user can just press a logout button in order to logout. What i have so far is:

```
const logout = () => {
     removeToken(['loginToken']);
}
```

when the button is pressed, it turns my cookie's value into undefined.
**before**

```
loginToken: 'asd99123jsd9asd9231'
```

**after**

```
loginToken: 'undefined'
```

From the documentation i read, it is supposed to remove the cookies completely without even leaving a cookie variable. What could i possibly miss here? Thank you so much in advance. If you need any more information, I would be more than happy to give you please be patient as this is my first React project.

Comment: Removed django tag as it seems to be irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem with deleting cookies.
In my case, the cookie was the same when calling the removeCookie.
Then I found a solution:
I was not telling the path to remove the cookie function.

```
removeCookie('cookie-name',{path:'/'});
```

P.S. - Found solution here (another StackOverflow question): [cookies.remove('abc') not working in reactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861709/cookies-removeabc-not-working-in-reactjs/54861946)

Answer (score 5):

I hope this will help you.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [pwd, setPwd] = useState('');
    const [cookie, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies();

const handle = () => {
    setCookie('Name', name, { path: '/' });
    setCookie('Password', pwd, { path: '/' });
};

const handleRemove = () => {
    removeCookie('Name', { path: '/', domain: 'localhost' });
};

return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Name of the user:</h1>
        <input
            placeholder="Name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <h1>Password of the user:</h1>
        <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={pwd}
            onChange={(e) => setPwd(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div>
            <button onClick={handle}>Set Cookie</button>{' '}
        </div>
        <br />
        {cookie.Name && (
            <div>
                Name: <p>{cookie.Name}</p>
            </div>
        )}
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleRemove}>Remove Cookie</button>{' '}
        </div>
    </div>
);
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The [remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/remove) method of the cookies API deletes a cookie, given its name and URL.

```
browser.cookies.remove('loginToken')
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply should give the cookie name. no need for the extra `[]`

```
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies();

useEffect(() => {
   removeCookie(cookiesName);
}, [removeCookie]);
```

see the refences in the react-cookie npm doc:

> removeCookie(name, [options]) Remove a cookie
>
> name (string): cookie name
>
> options (object)